# Using InstanceDefaultDataPath and InstanceDefaultLogPath in CREATE DATABASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to use the default path for a `FILENAME` as passed to a `CREATE DATABASE` statement, like this:

```
DECLARE @MdfPath NVARCHAR(1024) = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath');

EXEC ('
    CREATE DATABASE [SoTest]
    ON PRIMARY
    (NAME = N''SoTest'', FILENAME = N''' + @MdfPath + '/SoTest.mdf'')
    LOG ON
    (NAME = N''SoTest_log'', FILENAME = N''' + @MdfPath + '/SoTest_log.ldf'')
');
```

But that gives me:

> Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

This makes sense because `SERVERPROPERTY(...)` gives back a `SQL_VARIANT`.

I could follow the error message suggestion like this:

```
DECLARE @MdfPath NVARCHAR(1024) = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS NVARCHAR(1024));
DECLARE @LdfPath NVARCHAR(1024) = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS NVARCHAR(1024));
```

And then it works... for my scenario. But [the appropriate MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql) does not specify a "*Base data type*" for these two properties (like it does for others), so I won't know for sure if my code is safe and portable.

Is it known what the underlying data type is for these two server properties? Is it safe to convert to an NVARCHAR like above? Is there a more appropriate way to specify a path for `CREATE DATABASE` statements?

Comment: The only thing that's an *actual* portability issue is that there's no way to know what the path separator for the system is. You're using `/`, and Windows should accept that, but even so a dedicated function for path joining wouldn't hurt. (I don't expect them to add this any time soon, though.)

Comment: Ah yeah that one I've tested. Windows doesn't mind the `/`, and it should make sure things also work on my mssql-linux docker containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to convert to nvarchar, and I do the same as you plan in some of my scripts. Never had a problem

Even if the [base type is int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql)

```
SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('CollationID') AS nvarchar(10))
```

It's probably a documentation oversight. The newer properties ("Applies to:" and SQL Server 2012+) have no base datatype. Older properties do